# Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource EventHandlerLambdaFunction

Tags: amazon-web-services, resources, aws-cloudformation, serverless

Can anyone help me find what's wrong?

I'm importing this cloudformation resources in my serverless yml.
This is my function config:

```
Resources:
  eventHandler:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: eventLambda/
      Handler: dist/app.eventHandler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      FunctionName: eventHandler
```

This where I'm referencing it:

```
eventSourceRule:
    Type: 'AWS::Events::Rule'
    Properties:
      Name: eventSourceRule
      EventBusName: omnibus-${self:custom.stage}
      EventPattern: |
        {
          "source": ["op.api"]
        }
      RetryPolicy:
        MaximumRetryAttempts: 5
        MaximumEventAgeInSeconds: 900
      DeadLetterConfig:
        Type: SQS
        QueueLogicalId: EBRuleDLQ
      Targets:
        - Arn:
            Fn::GetAtt:
              - 'EventHandlerLambdaFunction'
              - 'Arn'
          Id: 'eventSourceRule'
```

Notice that I've already tried `eventHandler` and `EventHandler` and none of these worked.
That's the error I'm receiving:

```
The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource EventHandlerLambdaFunction
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have to add the logical name of  **resource**.
Replace `EventHandlerLambdaFunction` to actual resource name `eventHandler`.
You are not using the logical name of your Lambda resource you have defined.

---

You can try using the simple YAML syntax:

```
Targets:
  - Arn: !GetAtt eventHandler.Arn
```

Reference: [Fn::GetAtt AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html)